# Testing a method provided by autoload with Test::More

Tags: perl, testing, autoload, catalyst

I have a factory class which provides a bunch of similar methods by using autoload. For a longer list of different object types it can do things like

```
Factory->objects();
Factory->object(23);
Factory->object(name => "foo");
```

Now I want to write a test for this class. I started with something like this:

```
use Test::More;

BEGIN { use_ok 'Factory' }

my $objects = Factory->objects;

# more tests following ...
```

The test fails in the line with `Factory->objects` because it implicitly checks if `Factory` can do `objects()`. I could not find some documentation for this. But if I run the same call in a non-testing script it works perfectly.

How to test this?

**Update:** ARGH, I've just recognized I put all of this in the test for the `Factory` model class in my Catalyst app. Well, this model class is an *Adapter* for the `Factory` class in my external model (which I actually intended to test). The work perfectly for the model itself. Still would appreciate to know how to test method from an adapted class. This is how the adapter class looks like:

```
package MyCatalystApp::Model::Factory;
use Moose;

extends 'Catalyst::Model';
extends 'Catalyst::Model::Adaptor';

__PACKAGE__->config(class => 'MyModel::Factory');
```

`MyModel::Factory` is the same class as `Factory` in the original question. I skipped the difference between Catalyst and the model in the original question for simplification.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply add "`use Factory;`" before calling the tests (after `use_ok`).

Comment: As a note - I'm pretty sure it will work, but based on my limited but non-trivial knowledge of Test::More, I can't quite figure out WHY would use_ok not play well with AutoLoader. I'm hoping someone with more clue (Schwern?) can add a more definitive answer

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work for me. ATM I am trying to build some short example code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Now the tests work and your advice really makes no difference at all.

Comment: @halo - now THAT makes a lot more sense (as I noted in the first comment)

Answer (score 0):

Catalyst instantiates models (components) during setup_components by calling the [COMPONENT](http://search.cpan.org/~jjnapiork/Catalyst-Runtime-5.90042/lib/Catalyst/Component.pm#COMPONENT%28%24c,%24arguments%29) method. I guess Catalyst::Model::Adaptor relies on this happening.

When you `use MyCatalystApp::Model::Factory` you can get away with calling `my $factory = MyCatalystApp::Model::Factory->COMPONENT()` from within tests instead of `new()` to make them work.